# Error in Internet Explorer8 Windows 7: this tab has been recovered 

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8, browser-tabs

I get this error every time I open Internet Explorer8 in Windows 7, and a popup appear which says: this tab has been recovered and it close open the tab that I can't even surf a page (any page) with Internet Explorer8, and after a while it crashes and close the program with no such an obvious error, I tried these methods to solve the problem but it doesn't work:

1. Reset Internet Explorer settings
2. Run Internet Explorer without Add-ons
3. Scanned system for viruses with Eset Smart Security 4, there was no viruses.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across this problem when  Internet Explorer 8 tries to load a page it doesn't like.
What page does it try and open when it launches?

Bit of a long shot, but try going into Internet Options (via Control Panel) and select 'Use blank' in the Homepage section.

You could also try downloading '[Microsoft Fix it Center](http://fixitcenter.support.Microsoft.com/Portal/)' which has a troubleshooting action for 'Internet Explorer freezes or crashes'. From the description it looks for misbehaving plug-ins which you say you've disabled, but maybe worth a try.

Failing that, try uninstalling/reinstalling Internet Explorer 8. With Windows 7 this is done from:
`'Control Panel > Programs > Turn Windows features on or off'`.
Deselect Internet Explorer 8 and reboot.